# How to put impl trait return value in struct without using a box?

Tags: rust, types

I want to convert the return type of the following function signature into a struct:

```
fn h(input: &Input) -> impl Iterator<Item=(u64, impl Iterator<Item=X>, Other, Structs)>
```

How to deal with the impl traits?

1. I don't want to Box and allocate heap, possible no_std environment
2. I can't expand the iterator because it involves unnameable closures
3. I don't want to collect it into a concrete type because I want it lazy; it is computationally expensive and I don't necessarily need the values

Do I have any other options?

Comment: If you are ok using Nightly, you can use `#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]` ([RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2515-type_alias_impl_trait.md))

Answer (score 1):

You can try using generics. Define your struct to contain a generic type `I`, which will be your iterator:

```rust
struct Foo<I> {
    iter: I,
}
```

Now you can specify your function to return `Foo`, providing `impl Iterator` as the type parameter.

```rust
fn h(input: &Input) -> Foo<impl Iterator<Item=(u64, impl Iterator<Item=X>, Other, Structs)>>
```

Here is a similar [playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f1f44f86277bb2e5f3065f4cc38b704f) that returns a struct wrapping an empty iterator using `impl Iterator` as the type parameter.

Comment: Thank you. It technically answers my question but unfortunately doesn't solve the problem I was after (which admittedly I did not spell out). I wanted to not have to spell out all the pieces of data in function signatures using this struct, but it seems that I would have to like this. Perhaps there is no other way with Rust.